# error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c

This error is coming out of no where!! Please help!The error is coming that declaration or statement at end of input is needed! What should be done in this case?? Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "jatin.h"

int main() {
  int t1, t2;
  char sc1, sc2;
  while (1) {
    printf("Enter a temperature and a scale\n");
    scanf("%d %c", &t1, &sc1);
    convert_temp(t1, sc1, &t2, &sc2);
    printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", t1, sc1, t2, sc2);
      }
void convert_temp(int t1, char sc1, int *t2, char *sc2) 
{
  if (sc1 == 'F' || sc1 == 'f') 
  {
*t2 = (t1-32)/1.8;

  }
  else if (sc1 == 'C' || sc1 == 'c') 
  {

*t2 = (1.8*t1)+32;

  }
  else
  {
      printf("Enter valid temperature");
  }
}
```

Comment: Format&indent this mess properly and you will see.

Comment: Normally that error occurs when a `}` was missed somewhere in the code, witch is your case.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `}` bracket closing the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues I could spot out include :

1. No ending `}` for `main()`
2. Infinite while loop :

   ```
   while (1) {
   // ominous loop with no exit
   // Be ready to cut the hard line.
   }
   ```
3. No indentation &
4. An unused header `jatin.h`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no closing '}' bracket in the main () function.